# Save and Read a Python Dictionary to/from CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I want to perform a simple operation, store a python dictionary into a csv file and then later read it from the file as a dictionary.

My dictionary maps a string to a list of numpy arrays, for example:

```
d = {'x': [array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])], 'y': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```

So I would like to store this dictionary as a csv and then recreate the dictionary from the file in a different program.

I've tried using python's `csv` module to write the dictionary to a csv file but had trouble storing the list of multidimensional numpy arrays properly. When I used the module to read it back it read back blank rows in the csv file.

I also tried to use `pandas`, but wasn't able to figure out how to use the `read_csv()` method to read a list of numpy arrays back from the dictionary.

Comment: Don't use csv. Use pickle (if your other program is also a python-program; else: use JSON or something similar which is more efficient through using binary-type storing; e.g. msgpack)! *Edit:* If it's just a list of numpy arrays, read up numpys docs as there are special storage-methods like [savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html)

Comment: @sascha is right. Take a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: Would pickle be able to load back the entire dictionary as is? Some of the numpy values are more complex float numbers, I just used ints for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Read up the official pickle docs (it's part of standard python) and your question will be answered. It get's more complex with storing classes/functions and co. but all native python-types or compositions of these (like a dict of str->list(float)) will be supported 100%. And again: consider numpy's savez!

Comment: Not sure if I can use savez because I need to preserve the dictionary structure as well, and I don't want to store one file for each list as the number of lists could get large. But I'll go ahead and try pickle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [610]: d = {'x': [np.array([2, 3, 4]), np.array([5, 6, 7])], 'y': [np.array(
     ...: [1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6])]}
In [611]: d
Out[611]: 
{'x': [array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])],
 'y': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]}

In [613]: np.save('test.npy',d)
In [614]: np.load('test.npy')
Out[614]: array({'x': [array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])], 'y': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]}, dtype=object)
```

So calling `save` on the dictionary, it wraps the dictionary in a object type array, and then saves that.  And elements of an object array are saved with their respective pickle method.  So it pickles a dictionary, and the lists within the dictionary.  Finally the arrays within the lists pickled with a version of the `np.save`.  Lots of nesting.  But it works.

And `item` can be used to pull the dictionary out of the object array:

```
In [616]: dd=np.load('test.npy').item()
In [617]: dd
Out[617]: 
{'x': [array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])],
 'y': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]}
```

And using `pickle` directly:

```
In [626]: pickle.dump(d, open('test.pkl','wb'))
In [627]: np.load('test.pkl')
Out[627]: 
{'x': [array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])],
 'y': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]}
In [629]: pickle.load(open('test.pkl','rb'))
Out[629]: 
{'x': [array([2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7])],
 'y': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]}
```

To write a `csv` from this dictionary I'd create a structured array with fields named 'x' and 'y'.  But I think I'd have to concatenate the arrays, so I can produce a 1d array.  The csv would then look something like:

```
x    y
2    1
3    4
....
```

Or if the subarrays are all the same length I might be able to produce

```
x    y
2 5  1 4
3 6  2 5
...
```

In any if you still want to go the csv route, you need to decide how represent the values as simple lines of columns.

Comment: Is the first the most efficient? I just need to store and reload the dictionary, it doesn't have to be a csv